# Can i add two google-services.json files in my app?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am using firebase admob in my android app, now i am looking for integrating the firebase FCMNotifications in my app,but in the process there is some confusion whether i can use two google-serices.json files in my app,can i get some resolutions if someone tried before?

Comment: The easier option is to merge them into an unique file

Comment: You probably should not use 2. Best is to remove the old one, and download a new one from Firebase, with all the correct settings. Normally, the google-services.json contains multiple sections

Answer (score 0):

you must download the new json that already contains admob and Notifications, and replace it with the previous one.